# Python: multiprocessing and requests to build a simple web scraper

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am writing a very simple web scraper to download pictures for a social science project. So far the scraper works perfectly but I am wondering if there is a way to speed it up using multiproccessing.

What I have done so far

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import csv
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import os, errno

df = pd.read_csv('/Path/to/source-file.csv')
urls = [x for y in df.values.tolist() for x in y]

links = urls[10::6]
names = urls[6::6]
location = urls[7::6]
date = urls[8::6]
gale = urls[12::6]

def picture_getter(picture):
    global page     #page number in article
    global article     #how many articles it has iterated through
    global page_num_total     #how many pages overall it iterated through
# for i in links:
    print('working on page {} in article {}'.format(page, article))
    page = page + 1
    try:
        os.makedirs("/New/directory/for-each/Article/{}/{}/{}".format(location[page_num],date[page_num],gale[page_num]))
        page = 1
        article = article + 1
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(picture, "/PAth/to/new-page/of/Articleinimageform{}/{}/{}/{}{}.jpg".format(location[page_num],date[page_num],gale[page_num], names[page_num], str(page)))
    page_num = page_num + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page_num = 0
    page = 0
    god_damnit = 1
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.map(picture_getter, links)
```

When I run this I get something like the following:

```
output
working on page 0 in article 1
working on page 0 in article 1
working on page 0 in article 1
working on page 0 in article 1
working on page 1 in article 1
None
working on page 1 in article 1
working on page 1 in article 1
working on page 1 in article 1
None
None
None
working on page 2 in article 1
working on page 2 in article 1
working on page 2 in article 1
None
working on page 2 in article 1
None
None
None
working on page 3 in article 1
working on page 3 in article 1
working on page 3 in article 1
working on page 3 in article 1
None
None
None
None
```

I am assuming that instead of having each process work on a different article all of them are working on the same article at the same time. So difference between a pin factory with some division of labor vs one where each worker does every part of the pin. This is not what I want but I am assuming that the way I iterate through the list of sources in my function is to blame here. What I want is something more along the lines of:

```
worker process 1: working on page 1 article 1
worker process 2: working on page 2 article 1
worker process 3: working on page 1 article 2
worker process 4: working on page 1 article 3
worker process 1: working on page 2 article 3
worker process 2: working on page 3 article 3
...
```

I have several questions.
Am I using the map and pool functions correctly?
Is there a better way to iterate through my list? It works properly for a normal for loop
Am I reading the output correctly? Are the the processes actually just working on the same page all the time?

Complete Amateur here.

Comment: Individual processes do not share memory so you need to provide them all of the data they need (the URL, the page, page number etc.) as arguments, not as shared globals. Also, in this particular case (waiting on I/O) you won't benefit from multiprocessing much, use threads instead as you can share the working memory between threads.

Comment: Thanks zwer! Could you also point me to some documentation I can read that would help with this.

Comment: Read up on [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) especially the [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) section if you insist to share a state between processes. As for `threading`, read up on [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) and how it makes an exception for I/O bound tasks.